# Is this the best way to display my returned value from javascript function?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, document.write

I am assigned with creating a basic HTML page displaying the largest states in america using each state as a stored javascript variable. For some reason I feel like this can be done easier then how i did it. Any suggestions?

```
<script>
var states = ["Alaska", "Texas", "California", "Montana", "New Mexico", "Arizona", "Nevada"];
var miles = [663267, 268581, 163696, 147042, 121589, 113998, 110561];
var index= "";
text="";
function listStates() {
    for (index=0; index < states.length; index++) {
            text += "<tr><td>" + states[index] ;    
            text += "</td><td>" + miles[index] ;
            text += "</td></tr>";
    }
    return text;
}
</script>

<section id="table">
<table width="307" height="45">
<tr><th width="40">Name</th><th width="65">Size</th></tr>
<script>
<!--
    var result = listStates();
    document.write(result);
//-->
</script>
</table>
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it would fit better on [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: In most case this will be the worst possible method.

Comment: Using `document.write` is usually not a great idea. Use DOM manipulation instead to create and append nodes. It would also be an improvement to not have two parallel arrays and instead have a single array of objects with `stateName` and `area`  (I assume it's area, despite the misleading name).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `document.write` defeats the purpose of JavaScript dynamicity, you should use DOM Manipulation instead, specifically, tables have their own methods to accomplish what you ask for.

Also, may I suggest an `object{}` instead of two sepparate `arrays[]` to assign miles to states? See it working [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/79gjvn4f/).

### HTML

```
<section>
    <table width="307" height="45">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th width="40">Name</th>
                <th width="65">Size</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody></tbody>
    </table>
</section>
```

I've sepparated your table into `<thead>` and `<tbody>` to fit more accordingly to HTML5 Standarts.

### JavaScript

```
states = {
    "Alaska": 663267,
        "Texas": 268581,
        "California": 163696,
        "Montana": 147042,
        "New Mexico": 121589,
        "Arizona": 113998,
        "Nevada": 110561
}

window.addEventListener("load",function(){
    table = document.querySelector("table");
    listStates(table);
});


function listStates(table) {
    var body = table.tBodies[0];
    for (var state in states) {
        var miles = states[state];
        var row = body.insertRow();
        var stateCell = row.insertCell();
        stateCell.innerHTML = state;
        var mileCell = row.insertCell();
        mileCell.innerHTML = miles;
    }
}
```

### Steps

- First, we align states and miles inside an object (simplest way of storing key-value pairs).
- Then, we get the table using a `querySelector`, if you have more than one table you should get them via `getElementById` and assign the proper id's to each one.
- Then, we call the `listStates()` function that will take a *table* parameter, and we pass our table.
- Inside said function we get the `<table>`'s `<tbody>` by accessing the first element of the`table.tBodies` property.
- Then, we iterate over the properties inside the states object, and we use the DOM built-in table methods like `insertRow()` and `insertCell()` to achieve our purpose.

Hope this helps you!

### Updates

Here is a **code snippet** showing this at work (added the window.onload event)

```js
states = {
  "Alaska": 663267,
  "Texas": 268581,
  "California": 163696,
  "Montana": 147042,
  "New Mexico": 121589,
  "Arizona": 113998,
  "Nevada": 110561
}

window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  table = document.querySelector("table");
  listStates(table);
});


function listStates(table) {
  var body = table.tBodies[0];
  for (var state in states) {
    var miles = states[state];
    var row = body.insertRow();
    var stateCell = row.insertCell();
    stateCell.innerHTML = state;
    var mileCell = row.insertCell();
    mileCell.innerHTML = miles;
  }
}
```

```css
table {
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 14px;
}
thead {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <table width="307" height="45">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th width="40">Name</th>
        <th width="65">Size</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
  </table>
</section>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This was extremely helpful and well detailed. One question though?!
What are you doing in your for loop condition

Comment: It's a [**for..in loop**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in), really useful while iterating through object properties, you basically initiate a variable that will carry each property name inside some object, in this case the variable `state` inside `states`, to get the value of that property you need to select it in the object, via the bracket notation `states[state]`, in this case, `state[states]` is where I stored each mileage :) You are welcome!

Comment: Okay awesome. Unfortunately, I copied the code exactly, and the table doesnt show. Just the headers.

Comment: That's probably because you didn't execute it after the page loaded, you see JSFiddle automatically excutes your code after the load event, causing me to forget that part, I've updated my code and it should work now :) For future reference, every time you need to work with the DOM, use the window load event.